# Вывод массива структур на экран в виде таблицы

Tags: c++, структуры

Хранение данных необходимо организовать в виде массива
структур. В программе должны быть реализованы следующие функции:

1. Создание новой записи;
2. Вывод массива структур на экран в виде таблицы;

Помогите я тупой

```
struct person {
    char* name1, *name2, *name3, *sex, *nationality;
    int height, weight;
    int year, month, number;
    long long phone_number;
    int zip_code;
    char* country, *region, *city, *street;
    int house, apartment;
};

void PrintArr(person per[], int index);
void PrintHeader();
void line1();
void line2();
void PrintElement(int index);
void PrintHeader();

{
for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
{
    printf("Людина : %d\n", i + 1);

    printf("Ведіть Прізвище людини:");
    per[i].name1 = new char[12];
    cin.get();
    cin.getline(per[i].name1, 12);

    printf("Ведіть Імя людини:");
    per[i].name2 = new char[12];
    cin.get();
    cin.getline(per[i].name2, 12);

    printf("Ведіть По-батькові людини:");
    per[i].name3 = new char[17];
    cin.get();
    cin.getline(per[i].name3, 17);

    printf("Ведіть стать людини:");
    per[i].sex = new char[55];
    cin.get();
    cin.getline(per[i].sex, 55);

    printf("Ведіть національність людини:");
    per[i].nationality = new char[55];
    cin.get();
    cin.getline(per[i].nationality, 55);

    printf("Ведіть ріст людини:");
    scanf_s("%d", &per[i].height);

    printf("Ведіть вагу людини:");
    scanf_s("%d", &per[i].weight);

    printf("Ведіть рік народження людини:");
    scanf_s("%d", &per[i].year);

    printf("Ведіть місяць народження людини:");
    scanf_s("%d", &per[i].month);

    printf("Ведіть число народження людини:");
    scanf_s("%d", &per[i].number);

    printf("Ведіть номер телефону людини:");
    scanf_s("%d", &per[i].phone_number);

    printf("Ведіть zip code людини:");
    scanf_s("%d", &per[i].zip_code);

    printf("Ведіть країну людини:");
    per[i].country = new char[15];
    cin.get();
    cin.getline(per[i].country, 15);

    printf("Ведіть регіон людини:");
    per[i].region = new char[12];
    cin.get();
    cin.getline(per[i].region, 12);

    printf("Ведіть місто людини:");
    per[i].city = new char[12];
    cin.get();
    cin.getline(per[i].city, 12);

    printf("Ведіть вулицю людини:");
    per[i].street = new char[14];
    cin.get();
    cin.getline(per[i].street, 14);

    printf("Ведіть будинок людини:");
    scanf_s("%d", &per[i].house);

    printf("Ведіть квартиру людини:");
    scanf_s("%d", &per[i].apartment);
    printf("\n");
}}

int main(){
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    const int index = 1;
    person arr[index];
    int selection;

    do
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("Виберіть потрібну функцію:\n");
        printf("1 - Створення нового запису\n");
        printf("2 - Виведення масиву структур на екран у вигляді таблиці\n");
        printf("3 - Пошук запису за параметром\n");
        printf("4 - Видалення запису із масиву\n");
        printf("5 - Сортування масиву структур за деяким параметром\n");
        printf("0 - Вихід\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &selection);

        switch (selection)
        {
        case 1: Input(arr, index); break;
        case 2: PrintArr(arr, index); break;
        case 3: (arr, index); break;
        case 4: (arr, index); break;
        case 5: (arr, index); break;
        case 0: (arr, index); break;
        default:printf("Такой функции нет\n");
        }
    } while (selection != 0);

    system("pause");
}

void line1() {      
    printf_s("_________________________________________________\n");
}

void line2() {
    printf_s("-------------------------------------------------\n");
}

void PrintArr(person per[]){
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        PrintHeader();
        PrintElement(i);
        line2();
    }
}

void PrintHeader() {
    line1();
    printf_s("|  №  ");
    printf_s("|    Ім'я    |");  //12
    printf_s("   Прізвище  |");  //12
    printf_s(" По-батькові  |"); //14
    printf_s("стать|"); //4
    printf_s("національність|");//6
    printf_s(" зріст |");//5
    printf_s("вага|");//5
    printf_s("рік|");//4
    printf_s("місяць|");//5
    printf_s("день|");//4
    printf_s("Номер телефона|");//20
    printf_s("zip_code|");//20
    printf_s("країна |");
    printf_s("регіон |");
    printf_s("місто |");
    printf_s("вулиця |");
    printf_s("будинок|");
    printf_s("квартира |");
    line2();
}

void PrintElement(person per[], int index) {
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        printf_s("|%5d", index);
        printf_s("|%-12s|", per[i].name1);
        printf_s("%-12s|", per[i].name2);
        printf_s("%-14s|", per[i].name3);
        printf_s("%4d|", per[i].sex);
        printf_s("%4d|", per[i].nationality);
        printf_s("%6d|", per[i].height);
        printf_s("%6d|", per[i].weight);
        printf_s("%5d|", per[i].year);
        printf_s("%5d|", per[i].month);
        printf_s("%5d|", per[i].number);
        printf_s("+%-14lld|\n", per[i].phone_number);
        printf_s("%5d|", per[i].zip_code);
        printf_s("%5d|", per[i].country);
        printf_s("%5d|", per[i].region);
        printf_s("%5d|", per[i].city);
        printf_s("%5d|", per[i].street);
        printf_s("%5d|", per[i].house);
        printf_s("%5d|", per[i].apartment);
    }
}
```

проблема в том что я не могу вывод массива структур на экран в виде таблицы.
Я прописав уже функции, но оно не работает.

Comment: Так это c++ или c?

Answer (score 1):

У Вас метка  С++

Чтобы вывести элемент структур в stdout, проще всего перегрузить оператор <<. 
класса std::ostream

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const YouStruct& obj) {.....}
```

В этой прегрузке, Вы можете написать любой удобный Вам формат вывода содержимого объекта структуры.

Далее просто кидайте объект в cout)

Вот мини пример :

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

namespace test {
    struct s
    {
        s(int a, double b, char c) : a(a), b(b), c(c) {}

        int a;
        double b;
        char c;
    };


    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const s& obj) {
        out << obj.a << " " << obj.b << " " << obj.c;
        return out;
    }
}



int main()
{
    std::vector<test::s> v{{1, 1.1, 'a'}, {2, 1.2, 'b'}, {3, 1.3, 'c'}};

    for (const auto& val : v) {
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `namespace std {` ??? Это новый стандарт?

Comment: @ヒミコ Я не понял Ваш вопрос....

Comment: @Andrey А разве не запрещено добавлять сущности в `namespace std`? Оператор лучше перегрузить в том же простарнстве имен, в котором находится класс.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat не рекомендуется. Но на практике мы ведь понимаем, что делам. А делаем это для большей наглядности... Все же зависит от того где пишут и что там принято)))))

Comment: @HolyBlackCat все-же прислушаюсь к Вашему мнению и изменю ответ